# Can anyone tell me which Jquery plugin satisfies my requirement

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have two tables left_table and right_table, 
1. I should select any row of left table and drop into right_table
2. select multiple rows from the left table and drop to right_table.
3. Select random items using Ctrl+Mouse Click in left table and drop them to right_table
4. Select multiple items using Shift+Mouse Click in left table and drop them to right_table

I have tried some like :
1. http://plugins.scbfolio.com/jquery_drag_drop_select/
2. http://thechriswalker.net/select-drag/

but the above links dont satisfy my req-3 and req-4

Can anyone suggest me a jquery plugin which can solve my requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on requirement 3?

Comment: Ctrl+Mouse click as we do in Windows folder. random row selection using Ctrl+mouse click

Answer (score 0):

Your first link seems to satisfy all your requirements: http://plugins.scbfolio.com/jquery_drag_drop_select/

At least in Google Chrome

Comment: This is not able to meet req-4. This is the main problem